# What are flimsy numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary, oeis

I was reading the binary weight sequence information on OEIS (its number is A000120), when I found [this](https://oeis.org/A005360) sequence too. Their called the flimsy numbers, but I can't seem to find anything on google about them (minus one random email that is in reference to the OEIS). I don't see anything particularly interesting about these numbers. Is there anything of note about the flimsy numbers, or their counterpart the sturdy numbers?

Comment: Did you read the Stolarsky paper linked in the OEIS entry?

Comment: You may be able to track down the author of the sequence (listed at the bottom of the entry).

Comment: Here's a publisher's link to a recent paper on this subject,  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-015-9768-7

Comment: @John I tried. But he doesn't have any papers that seem to be about flimsy or sturdy numbers.

Comment: If he's still around he may tell you if you email him.  One would think that if he authored the entry that it interested him.  Or it could be a wild goose chase. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been several years, but now that I've had some real math education I've been scrolling through my old questions and feel I'm equipped to actually read the OEIS article. According to the page, flimsy numbers are natural numbers $n$ such that

> some multiple of n has fewer ones in its binary expansion than does n.

What makes these numbers interesting is noted in this quote also from the OEIS,

> Stolarsky says "at least half the primes are flimsy."

The list of flimsy prime numbers is given by [A330696](https://oeis.org/A330696).